# When does ${\rm Hom}_S(R,S) \cong R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $S \subset R$ be two non-commutative rings and assume that $R$ is free of finite rank as an $S$-module and that $S$ is central subring of $R$. What are the (minimal) conditions such that:
                          $${\rm Hom}_S(R,S) \cong R\text{ as $R$-modules} ? $$

Here $R$ acts on ${\rm Hom}_S(R,S)$ via $r. \phi(x)=\phi(xr)$. One may prove that ${\rm Hom}_S(R,S) \cong R$ as $S$-modules.

For example, if $S=k$ is a field and $R$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra, the condition is equivalent to $R$ being a Frobenius algebra. Any references are welcome.

Comment: Are they not always isomorphic?

Comment: @Anonymous, they are always isomorphic as $S$-modules, but since not every finite-dimensional $k$-algebra is Frobenius they cannot be always isomorphic.

Comment: @Torsten I regard $R$ as a left $R$-module and I let $R$ acts on Hom$_S(R,S)$ via $r \cdot \phi(x)=\phi(rx)$.

Comment: Surely you mean $r\cdot\phi(x)=\phi(xr)$.  What you wrote is not a left action.

Comment: Also, they are not always isomorphic as $S$ modules.  In the case $R=\mathbb{R}[a,b]/\langle a^2,b^2,ab\rangle$ and  $S=\mathbb{R}[b]/\langle b^2\rangle$ both $R$ and ${\rm Hom}_S(R,S)$ are isomorphic to $S\oplus S$ as vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$.  However as $S$ modules they are quite different.  In the latter case $$(\mu_1+\mu_2b)(s_1,s_2)=((\mu_1+\mu_2b)s_1,\mu_1 s_2).$$ Hence the image of multiplication by $b$ is only 1-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$.  On the other hand, if $S$ is central in $R$ then they are isomorphic as $S$-modules, by @Anonymous now deleted answer.

Comment: @tkf Thanks for your comments. The example I had in my mind was with $S$ being the centre of $R$.

Comment: So should your question read "Let $S\subseteq R$ with $R$ a not necessarily commutative ring, and $S$ a  ring contained in the centre of $R$, with $R$ free and finite dimensional as a module over $S$.  Then $R$ acts on ${\rm Hom}_S(R,S)$ via  $(r\cdot\phi)x=\phi(xr)$.  With these definitions $R$ and ${\rm Hom}_S(R,S)$ are necesarrily isomorphic as left $S$ modules.  What further conditions would guarantee they are isomorphic as $R$ modules?"?

Comment: Yes, I will add make the suggested edits.

Comment: Thanks.  I once called this condition "Frobenius" in a submitted paper where $S$ was $\mathbb Z$ and the referee was rightly not happy, because as you say the term Frobenius refers to the case where S is a field.

Comment: Well the existence of such an isomorphism implies that there is a distinguished "linear form" in $\mathrm{Hom}_S(R,S)$: namely, the image of $1_R$ under the iso (which is unique up to ...?) In the classical case of Frobenius algebras over a field $S=k$, that is the "counit" $\epsilon: R \rightarrow k$, like the trace form in the case of matrix algebras or the augmentation for group rings. So maybe one can explore how much of the categorical approach (e.g. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Frobenius+algebra) can be generalised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but certainly this is a necessary condition for your condition to hold.

Let $S$ be a central subring of a (not necessarily commutative) ring $R$, with $R$ free and finite dimensional as a module over $S$.  Your condition is that $R$ is isomorphic to ${\rm Hom}_S(R,S)$ as left $R$ modules.  Equivalently, there exists a map $\epsilon\colon R\to S$ such that every $S$-linear homomorphism $R \to S$ may be written in the form $\epsilon(\_a)$ for a unique $a\in R$.

A necessary condition for such an $\epsilon$ to exist is that finitely generated projective $R$-modules are injective relative to $S$.  That is given an $R$-linear  map of left $R$ modules $f\colon A \to M$ such that $f$ has a left inverse as a map of $S$ modules, any $R$-linear map $h\colon A \to P$ (for $P$ a finitely generated projective module) may be extended to an $R$-linear map $M \to P$.

$$
A\stackrel f\to M
$$
$$h\downarrow \,\,\,\swarrow\quad$$
$$P\quad\quad$$

Proof: Suppose $\epsilon$ exists as above.  It is sufficient to consider the case $P=R$, as the property of being relatively injective extends in an obvious way to (finite) direct sums and summands.

Given $m\in M$ we have an element of ${\rm Hom}_S(R,S)$ given by $$\lambda\mapsto \epsilon(hg(\lambda m))$$ where $g$ is the $S$-linear left inverse to $f$.

Thus we have $\hat h(m)\in R$ such that $$\epsilon(hg(\lambda m))=\epsilon(\lambda \hat h(m),$$
for all $\lambda\in R$.  Then $\hat h$ is $R$-linear as for all $\lambda\in R$ we have $$\epsilon (\lambda \hat h(\mu m))=\epsilon(hg(\lambda\mu m))=\epsilon(\lambda\mu\hat h(m)).$$

Finally we note that $\hat hf=h$: $$\epsilon(\lambda\hat hf(a))=\epsilon(hg(\lambda f(a)))=\epsilon(hgf(\lambda a))=\epsilon(h(\lambda a))=\epsilon(\lambda h(a)),$$ for all $\lambda \in R, \,\, a \in A$.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful answer.

Comment: Thanks.  If you replace "$S$-modules" with "sets" in the definition of "injective relative to $S$" then you get the usual definition of injective.  In particular when $S$ is a field "injective relative to $S$" is just the same as "injective". e.g. finitely generated projective modules over a Frobenius algebra are injective in the usual sense.  However when doing homological algebra with coefficients in a ring (e.g. $\mathbb Z$), this relative result is really useful - e.g. $\mathbb Z[G]$ has your property for a finite group $G$, so the result is useful for group cohomology with integer coeffs.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that. Also, since last week, I have managed to dig some literature about this condition. As you mentioned in a previous past, this is very close to what people call a Frobenius extensions, in fact my condition will immediately imply that $R$ is a Frobenius extension of $S$.